# How to get zipped all changes from specified git branch

Tags: git, branch, archive

I would like to get all changed files from git's specified branch in git file.

So I'm changing branch to branch1 and then fire command:

```
git archive -o branch1.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)
```

but this command zips only last commit from branch1.
I would like to have all changes from all commits from branch1 in branch1.zip file.

Comment: *all changes from all commits* In what way, in what form? Do you want to store all diffs or all files in every commit? Why?

Comment: All files in every commit

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track! You just need to apply the command to every commit in the branch:

```
for commit_id in `git rev-list branch1`; do
    git archive -o branch1-$commit_id.zip $commit_id -- $(git diff --name-only $commit_id~ $commit_id)
done
```

Changed files from every commit are put in a separate `branch1-$commit_id.zip`.